# QGIS: Delete all records/rows with NULL values

Tags: qgis, null

I have joined a CSV file to a shapefile by a common key in QGIS. Not all records in the shapefile and CSV had corresponding keys.

This left some records in the shapefile as NULL.

i.e.

```
 City     School_ID   ID_no   Total
London    1234       1234     12
Glasgow   4321       4321     10
Bristol   4444       NULL     NULL
```

This is just a small slice of the data. The actual data has about 12000 records.

Is there any way to delete all records/rows with NULL values?

Comment: Can't you just sort the data, so all NULL values are on top or bottom of the attribute table, then manually highlight the rows and delete them? Even with 12000 records it should be easily done.

Comment: Hi @gHupf, my sentiments exactly. However, there only seems to be an option to delete fields, as opposed to delete rows.

Comment: Hi @BERA, thank you for your reply. I know ArcGis allows you to keep only matching records, but in QGIS when joining vectors - there does not appear to be an option to select "join only matcihng records".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the attribute table, choose Select by Expression and write `"FIELD_NAME" IS null` (replace FIELD_NAME with your actual field names, of course). Click "Select Features", then simply delete the resulting selected features.

Comment: Hi Nathan, Thank you for replying. There does not seem to be a delete button for records in the attributes view. The only delete button seems to correspond to fields or columns. THis is where I am having the issue.

Comment: Allow editing for the layer (maybe you have to save it as a shapefile first), then there's this nice red trash bin you can use to dispose of your unwanted features. You cannot delete single table fields, only rows or columns.

Comment: If you click on the number on the left of the attribute table, the whole row gets highlighted and you can just delete it.

Comment: You can also choose Edit->Cut features (or use the scissors icon that's right next to the trash bin) if you want to keep the features in your clipboard.

Comment: @Erik - thank you so much ! I did not have the editing setting on!

Comment: @BERA the "= NULL" part did not appear to work for me - but it may have just been my dataset. I ordered the data with NULL at the top and manually deleted the entries after turning on "toggle editing" as suggested by Erik

Comment: @kris_Co2 You use "IS" or "IS NOT" with "null", not "=". (That's because NULL isn't a value, so the value of your fields cannot be equal to it.)

Comment: @nathan thank you for the tip, I will try that next time. Thank you for everyone's help.